# Penalty or Fee for Filing a Return, When a Refund Is Due

Tags: united-states, taxes, penalty

Working on my 2016 Federal tax return, and I've reached the Estimated Tax Penalty line on Form 1040.

I'll get a refund, so my guess is that I won't owe tax penalties on taxes I owe, since I don't owe any taxes for that year?

From [this IRS page](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/filing-past-due-tax-returns), sounds like I may not have any penalties/fees to pay but may lose my refund? If I do have any penalties because I didn't late file, should I put those into the Estimated Tax Penalty line?

Comment: The penalties for filing and paying late are different from the estimated tax penalty. The estimated tax penalty would apply only if you owed estimated tax but didn't pay enough on each quarterly payment date. There is no place on the form to put penalties for filing or paying late. The IRS would compute these and send you a bill (if you owed them, which you don't, because you are due a refund).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'll get a refund, so my guess is that I won't owe tax penalties on
>   taxes I owe, since I don't owe any taxes for that year?

Correct, penalties/interest are for those who failed to pay what was due on time, there's no penalty for failing to claim what the IRS owes you.

> From this IRS page, sounds like I may not have any penalties/fees to
>   pay but may lose my refund?

After 3 years you forfeit your refund, your 2016 return was due April 2017, so you have until the April 2020 deadline to file before you lose your refund.